# Unboundedness of multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:\ell^2\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ be a linear operator given by

$T\left(\left\{\lambda_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_n\lambda_n $, where $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset \mathbb{K}$.

It is well-known that if $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in \ell^2$ then $T$ is continuous and $\|T\|=\|\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\|_2$. Is it true that $T$ is unbounded, if $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\not\in \ell^2$ ?

I have problem with constructing a sequence $\left\{\left\{\lambda_n^k\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ s.th. $\left\|\{\lambda_n^k\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\right\|_2\le 1$ for any $k$ and $\left|\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_n\lambda_n^k \right|\rightarrow \infty$ for $k\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Just an observation: your claim is an easy consequence of the Riesz representation theorem for Hilbert spaces.  If you can use/prove this, you'd avoid the need to construct such a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is it true that $T$ is unbounded, if $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\not\in \ell^2$?*

The fact that "if $f:\ell^2\to\mathbb{K}$ is linear and continuous, then there is $\{b_n\}\in\ell^2$ such that
$$f(\{\lambda_n\})=\sum b_n\lambda_n$$
for all $\{\lambda_n\}\in\ell^2$" is well know too (see, for example, Proposition 2.17 in [Fabian's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Fabian+Banach+space+theory&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZsr3zl_zJAhXJQ5AKHdvaCscQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Fabian%20Banach%20space%20theory&f=false)).

Therefore,
$$\{\alpha_n\}\notin\ell^2\quad \Rightarrow\quad  T\text{ is unbounded}$$

Comment: It's not only well-known, it's the [Riesz Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).

Comment: We know that if $T$ is bounded then there exist unique $\{b_n\}$ in $\ell^2$ s.th. $f\left(\{\lambda_n\}\right)=\sum b_n\lambda_n$, but why there is no $\{a_n\}\not\in\ell^2$ s.th. $f\left(\{\lambda_n\}\right)=\sum a_n\lambda_n $? If such exists then in particular $\sum (a_n-b_n)\lambda_n=0$. Why it implies $\{a_n\}=\{b_n\}$ ? If we have scalar product then it is obvious, but in our case ($ \{a_n\}\not\in \ell^2$) we can't use it.

Comment: @mikis We have $\sum(a_n-b_n)\lambda_n$ for all $\{\lambda_n\}\in \ell^2$. Taking $\{\lambda_n\}=(1,0,0,0,...)$ we get $a_1=b_1$; Taking $\{\lambda_n\}=(0,1,0,0,...)$ we get $a_2=b_2$ and so on. Thus $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$. In other words, $\{a_n\}=\{b_n\}$.

Comment: Right, thanks !